# Use git submodule without parent directory

Tags: git, docker

I have a git repository A which contains a submodule B. I am building the project inside B in Docker by copying the submodule directory inside my Dockerfile. The build script of the project B needs to do

```
git describe
```

this however does not work when the submodule has been copied out of the parent project. If I copy A along with B inside Docker this would work, but as the .git directory inside A is updated on every commit, this keeps invalidating the Docker cache, so a full rebuild of B takes place each time a commit in A takes place. Is there a way to achieve the caching.

Comment: Can you do the `git describe` before copying over the submodule?

Comment: I don't think you could do this as a sub-module. The "B" could be built separately and distributed as an NPM or Nuget module. I know that some build systems can cache NPM and Nuget packages.

Comment: The `git describe` is done by an install script which I do not have control over.

Answer (score 1):

> Use git submodule without parent directory

No, this isn't possible. The submodule must be a directory in the parent repository.

How would git tell the difference between files in the parent repository and those that are in the submodule?

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy `B` as a directory — clone it as a repository. Clone not from `A` but directly from `B`:

```
git clone /path/to/A/subpath/to/B
```

With such a clone `git describe` works.